# Node socket.io passing socket to other file

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, koa

I'm building my app and to make things simple let's say I have main file called *app.js* and file called *Rooms.js* in which I want to have all the functions to handle socket.io rooms etc.

In **app.js** I load my module:

```
var Rooms = require("./methods/Rooms")
Rooms.Rooms(io, socket);
```

In **/methods/Rooms.js**:

```
exports.Rooms = function(io, socket) {

  /* This function works as a "controller" to Rooms module */

    (... some code here ...)

    if (usersJoined == usersToStartGame) {
        startGame(roomid, io, socket)
    }
}

function startGame(roomid, io, socket) {
    io.to(roomid).emit('startGame')
    (... other stuff ...)
```

**It does work**, but I feel like I'm doing something wrong.

Do I really need to pass *io* and *socket* every time I make new function? Isn't there a easier way?

Comment: Why not pass io once and keep it in a variable in Rooms.js (or maybe share a bigger object with the context of your application) ? You could also have a factory (or a proptotypal object) to wrap the socket (that's what I do).

Comment: What is `socket` in this case? I was thinking it's `io`, but, normally `socket` refers to a single connection. If it is a single connection, passing it around is likely the only option. `io` on the other hand could be abstracted to it's own module that gets required where it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I found more elegant solution which satisfies me:
in app.js (which i renamed for clarity to **Server.js**)
i added to

```
var server = http.createServer(app.callback());
var io = socketio.listen(server);
```

the following:

```
exports.server = server
exports.io = io
```

And into `io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){ ... }` I added `exports.socket = socket`.

This allowed me to use Server.js module in **/methods/Rooms.js**:

`var Server = require('../Server')`

and later on in this file I simply had to change `socket.*`, `io.*` syntax  into `Server.socket.*`, `Server.io.*`.