# Node.js using socket.io in multiple .js files

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I want to be able to write functions in multiple .js files and use the same socket that is create in my main server.js

server.js:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var http = require('http')
var server = http.createServer(app)
var io = require('socket.io')(server)
var GOR = require('./gor')
var path = require('path');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

//handles get request and serves index.html
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});

//wait for server to start
server.listen(8080,()=>{
  console.log("server started");
  setInterval(emit_data,5000);
  emit_data();
  
  //setInterval(GOR.send_from_another_js,5000);
  //GOR.send_from_another_js(io);
})

function emit_data(){
    io.emit( 'update', "webserver.js");
}
```

As you can see from the code above, I have a function that emits to socket every 5 seconds and that works fine. I have confirmed it already.

All I want to do now, is to create a seperate.js file and keep all my functions there to make the code look cleaner. I name another .js file gor.js:

gor.js:

```
//I want to call this function in my webserver.js and transmit this socket
function send_from_another_js(io){
    console.log("function called");
    io.emit( 'update', "another_js");
}

module.exports = {
    send_from_another_js    
}
```

When I call this function in my server.js , it does not work:

```
server.listen(8080,()=>{
  console.log("server started");
  setInterval(GOR.send_from_another_js,5000);
  GOR.send_from_another_js(io);

})
```

What is correct way to use the same .io in other .js files? The above does not work.

**EDIT1**

In my .html, I wait for a message on socket:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    
    socket.on('update', function(number_to_set) {
    console.log("socket update received");
    document.getElementById('number1').innerHTML = number_to_set;

});
    
    var button = document.getElementById("operation_code_button");
    button.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    var val = document.getElementById("operation_code_input").value;
    console.log("socket clicked, emmiting data");
    socket.emit('button_click',val);
    
});

})
```

And in my .js file I emit to this socket every 5 seconds:

```
server.listen(8080,()=>{
    console.log("server started");
    setInterval(emit_data,5000);
    emit_data();
})
```

After 5 seconds, I can see that my webpage update data so everything works!!!

I want to declare the emit_data function inside another .js file and use it in my main .js file.

The function in my secondary .js file ( gor.js):

```
function send_from_another_js_1(io){
  io.emit( 'update', data);
}
```

I want to call it in my main .js the same way I call emit_data

Comment: Really nothing. I am thinking it may be due to the fact that I reinitialise sockets in my gor.js file. ```var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);```. Maybe I just need to import the existing one from webserver.js?

Comment: THe developer tool does not show anything even when the websocket is being made properly ( when I call it from the webserer.js without using gor.js) . The only relevant discussion that I have managed to find online : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31457994/node-socket-io-passing-socket-to-other-file . However, I am not sure how can I incorporate this solution to my project

Answer (score 0):

Edited:(3)
Trust it is what you are looking for...

"server.js"

```
const content = require('fs').readFileSync(__dirname + '/index.html', 'utf8');
const httpServer = require('http').createServer((req, res) => {
// serve the index.html file
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
res.setHeader('Content-Length', Buffer.byteLength(content));
res.end(content);
});

const io = require('socket.io')(httpServer);

const apple = require("./File2.js")
apple.send_from_another_js_1(io);
apple.send_from_another_js_2(io);

var port = 3000; //wamp server
var prompt = 'Open browser at http://localhost:'
httpServer.listen(port, () => {
console.log(prompt, port);
});
```

"File2.js"

```
function send_from_another_js_1(io){
  io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('file2_1_EventTrigged', function (data) {
  socket.emit('update1', "send_from_another_js_1(io) : "+ data);
  console.log("+++ function send_from_another_js_1(io) called");
  });
 });
}

function send_from_another_js_2(io){
  io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('file2_2_EventTrigged', function (data) {
  socket.emit('update2', "send_from_another_js_2(io) : "+ data);
  console.log("... function send_from_another_js_2(io) called");
  });
 });
}

module.exports = {
 send_from_another_js_1,
 send_from_another_js_2
}
```

"index.html"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="Content-Type" content="text/html">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <meta name="keywords" content="HTML, CSS, JavaScript">
 <meta name="author" content="Dr.Chaiya Tantisukarom">
 <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="public, max-age=31536000">
 <title>NodeJS socket.io</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1 style="text-align: center;">Hello another world</h1>
 <div style="text-align: center;">
  <span>
   <button onclick="file2_1()">file2_1</button>
  </span>
  <span>
   <button onclick="file2_2()">file2_2</button>
  </span>
 </div>

<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
 var socket = io();
 socket.on('connect',()=>{
  //alert('Connected');
 })

function file2_1(){
 socket.emit('file2_1_EventTrigged', "Hello file2_1, how are you today?");
}
socket.on('update1', (data)=>{
 alert(data);
})

function file2_2(){
 socket.emit('file2_2_EventTrigged', "Hi file2_2, trust you are ok.");
}
socket.on('update2', (data)=>{
 alert(data);
})

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Cheers !!!

Comment: I try to pass it as a parameter because I did not know what other methods are possible? I Have rewritten my original question and simplified it quite a bit so it is easier to understand. I simply want to use io.emit function outside my main webserver.js. In the future I may create even more .js files where I will also want to use io.emit function.

Comment: If my understanding is correct, I  initialise all variables in my webserver.js ```var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var request = require('request');
var fetch = require("node-fetch");
var path = require('path');
var GOR = require("./gor.js");``` And I am not allowed to reinitialise them in my gor.js. I must pass the existing ones from the webserver.js but I am not sure how.

Comment: Found another very simmilar thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653617/socket-io-listen-events-in-separate-files-in-node-js. The only difference is that he is not trying to perform io.emit.  I am still not able to modify my project so I can use io.emit from another .js file.

Comment: I am not fully understanding what you mean.  Still havent found a solution how to use io.emit in another .js file

Comment: I copied and pasted a code from link you provided. I edited my answer above. You may pls try. I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: See my Edited:(2)
:)

Comment: Il test that tommorow. Il let you know if I get that to work. Thank you for all help

Comment: Hello sir. Could you confirm something for me please. The code in in File1.js is not exactly what I need. I do not want to have a nameless function and I do not want to emit a message on connection. I want to declare a function with name and then emit some data whenever the function is called. I must get it to work with this function ```function send_from_another_js(io){
 console.log("function called");
 io.emit( 'update', "another_js");
}```

Comment: Please check my initial function. I have this function ```send_from_another_js()``` and I want to use this function from another .js files. In this .js files there will be many functions that I will use. This is just one of them

Comment: See my Edited:(3)

Comment: Thanks for helping but its not what I need! I do not understand why you use on connection and other methods. I only want to emit. The function in gor.js must be ```function send_from_another_js_1(io){
  io.emit( 'update', data);
}```. Check my initial post I include EDIT1 to explain as much as I can

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for your server to get initialized. You are calling your function before socket.io is ready. That's why io.emit function is 'undefined'.

```
server.listen(8080,()=>{
  GOR.send_from_another_js(io);
})
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. That makes sense. However, there is still something wrong. ```server.listen(8080,()=>{
  console.log("server started");
  GOR.send_from_another_js(io);
  GOR.send_from_another_js(io);
})``` Seems to work fine. However, I want this to be called every 5 second. When I do this : ```server.listen(8080,()=>{
  console.log("server started");
  setInterval(GOR.send_from_another_js,5000);
  send_from_another_js(io);
}) ```. It gives me an error on the 2nd iteration

Comment: Updated my initial question ***UPDATE2*** for further testing according to your solution.

Answer (score 0):

When you call this:

```
server.listen(8080,()=>{
    console.log("server started");
    setInterval(GOR.send_from_another_js,5000);
    GOR.send_from_another_js(io);
})
```

`setInterval()` isn't providing a parameter for `GOR.send_from_another_js()`, so io becomes undefined.

To fix this, I would use a second lambda expression inside of your `setInterval()` call.

```
server.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log("server started");
    setInterval(() => {
        GOR.send_from_another_js(io);
    }, 5000);
    GOR.send_from_another_js(io);
});
```